# Onclick Javascript fails identify Resultset

Tags: javascript, custom-button, onclick, detail-page

I have below code where I get a run-time error as 'Unexpected Identifier'. My Resultset is not getting evaulated properly. Can someone please help?

**Onclick Javascript code in Detail Page button**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}
var user = sforce.connection.getUserInfo();
var check=false;
var count = sforce.connection.query("SELECT COUNT() FROM Contract_vod__c WHERE Signature_Available_abv__c = false and Account_Name_abv__c='{!Account.Id}'");
alert('Count@Check'+count);
check=sforce.apex.execute("CheckAOCAccess","AOCAccess",{LoggedUser:"{!User.Id}"});
alert('check@'+check);
var vUrl = '/apex/ABV_AoCSignatureCapturOnline?actId={!Account.Id}';
if(check == 'true' && count>0)
{alert('check@1'+check);
alert('count@@1'+count);
window.open(vUrl);} 
else if(check == 'false')
{alert('check@2'+check); alert('You are have not the privilege for Acknowledgement of Contents!');}
else {alert('count@2'+count); alert('You have no Acknowledgement of Contents pending to sign!');}
```

Comment: What is Resultset and Statement? And you are usign this on button click. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current main error is this line here:

```
var count = sforce.connection.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM Contract_vod__c WHERE Signature_Available_abv__c = false and Account_Name_abv__c=:"+{!Account.Id});
```

The ":" bind expression is only valid in Apex Code, not in any other language where SOQL might be used. Here's the correct way to write that line:

```
var count = sforce.connection.query("SELECT COUNT() AS total FROM Contract_vod__c WHERE Signature_Available_abv__c = false and Account_Name_abv__c='{!Account.Id}'");
```

This will place the account's Id in between two quotes, which is how SOQL expects the query to be written.

Comment: Thanks but it now throws exception as 'count()' is not identifiable. I have updated my latest version code.

Comment: It's now saying the select query as faultstring.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner Yes, sorry, it's `count()` not `count(*)`. I always forget that one, too.

Answer (score 0):

replace int with var on count initialization

Comment: Sorry I changed my mistakes and updated the code. Though it shows same error.

Answer (score 0):

Paste the JavaScript from the 3rd line to the end into http://jshint.com/ and you will see a number of errors e.g. you have `int` instead of `var` and `Statement` instead of `var`. JavaScript does not support strongly typed variables.

First correct those errors. Then when you run the code also check your browser's console to ensure no runtime errors are reported.

Comment: Hello Keith. Sorry I changed my mistakes and updated the code. Though it shows same error.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner You still have `int check` instead of `var check`.

Comment: Changed it, now it says 'Invalid or unexpected token'.